# Meaning of "or" in "working on applications to sell or for any other purpose"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, conjunctions

A licence reads:

> If you are an individual working on your own applications to sell or
>   for any other purpose, you may use the software to develop and test
>   those applications.

I'm having difficulties interpreting the meaning of the sentence, is the part *or for any other purpose* related to the verb *sell* which means that you can either sell or do whatever you want with the applications, or does it have another interpretation?

Comment: I think the key is that you are an individual (not a company) working on your own applications (not someone else's). Now that that is established whether you plan to sell your application or do something else with it (give it away, use it yourself, etc) It's all good.

Comment: You may also find  [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com) of interest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *for any other purpose* is an alternative to *to sell*. Individuals may have a number of purposes in mind when working on their own applications; one of these may be selling them.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps your intention is to sell whatever you produce with your own application, but it may not be so. Then, other possibilities ("**do something else**") would be to give them to your friends, to keep them to yourself, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It can be taken to mean:

You can use the software to develop an application whether you intend to sell the application or not.

Or:

You can use the software to develop an application whether the function of the application is to sell something or whether it does not function to sell something.

The first is the fairly obvious interpretation, but from let's say a "legalistic" perspective, it could be read in the second way.